# I can't set the top button in Android Kotlin webview, so please tell me how to implement it

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview

The top button is implemented on the Android native screen, so you can understand the operation flow, but there is no top button in the web view, so I don't know how to set it.

android native screen

[image]

android webview screen

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
    public void onClickedFloatingTop(View view) {
       
        WebView webView = getCurrentWebView();
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
            webView.loadUrl(Constants.JAVASCRIPT_FLOATING_TOP);
        }

      
        final VODView vodView = getCurrentVODView();
        if (vodView != null) {
            vodView.closeOffScreenVideo(ImageUtil.getDisplayHeight(getContext()), true);
        }


        setMainHeaderPositionAsDefault();

        MainFrameView mainFrameView = getFragmentByIndex(mCurrentPosition);
        if (mainFrameView.homeFrameView != null) {
            mainFrameView.homeFrameView.goTop();
        } else if (mainFrameView.tvShoppingFrameView != null) {
            mainFrameView.tvShoppingFrameView.goTop();
        } else if (mainFrameView.giftFrameView != null) {
            mainFrameView.giftFrameView.goTop();
        } else if (mainFrameView.ssagundealFrameView != null) {
            mainFrameView.ssagundealFrameView.goTop();
        }
    }
```

layout_floating.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http:

//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_btn_top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_top"
        android:onClick="onClickedFloatingTop" />
</FrameLayout>
```

MainFramView.java

```
   if (mRootView == null) {
            mRootView = inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_main, this);

            mViewBtnShow = (FrameLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_hide_main);

            mPullToRefreshVodView = (MainPullToRefreshVodView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_vod_view);

            mLoadingImage = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_img);
            mLoadingImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_animation);
            mLoadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mLoadingImage.getBackground();

            // floating top 설정
            mFloatingTop = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.floating_top_button);

            mNativeFrameLayout = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_native);

            nativeLoadingView  = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.sv_native_bg_img);

            // VOD 웹뷰 설정
            createVodWebView();

            // network error view - 아이콘 위치 설정
            View networkErrorView = mVodView.getNetworkErrorView();
            int headerHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_header_height);
            int headerTabHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_header_tab_height);
            int paddingBottom = networkErrorView.getPaddingBottom() + headerHeight + headerTabHeight;
            networkErrorView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, paddingBottom);
```